# Preserving the mask on a UIImage when converting it to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uiimage, masking

I'm working on an iOS app with Parse that requires profile pictures to be in the shape of hexagons.  Right now, I'm downloading the PFFile from Parse, grabbing that image and then masking it with a hexagon.  This works well for simple views like the profile screen (masking is only required once), but the app suffers severe performance issues when masking a collection view with a list of followers' profile images.

In my mind, the best solution would be to upload the profile pictures to Parse already masked correctly, so all I have to do is pull them down and display them. Here's the code that I used to do this in my sign up view controller:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

UIImage *chosenPicture = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

[EVNUtility maskImage:chosenPicture withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MaskImage"] withCompletionBlock:^(UIImage *maskedImage) {

    self.profileImageView.image = maskedImage;
    self.pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(maskedImage);

}];

}
```

The image comes back correctly masked from my utility function, however when I use UIImagePNGRepresentation (or the JPG equivalent) to convert the UIImage to data (this data is then uploaded to Parse), the image loses its mask and is square again.

**How can I keep the mask when converting a UIImage to NSData?**

I've tried a couple of things, but I'm guessing this is due to my fuzzy understanding of how masking is done and if it affects the underlying image.  Here's the reference I used for masking my image:  http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Comment: There is a problem in your example code. Where did `newImage` come from? Are you sure you are passing the correct image to `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`? In your code above, you are not. Also, the fact that the actual masking occurs in your `EVNUtility` class method obscures this example a bit. I think it would be better to show us the code you are using to perform the masking. Otherwise, any answer is just a guess (and just assumes you are masking correctly).

Comment: @ToddDitchendorf that `newImage` is a typo and leftover from code I was writing to experiment with another solution.  I've edited my original question.  The code in 'EVNUtility' is replicated from the link I posted at the end of my question; the 'profileImageView' displays the image correctly, so I know that the mask is lost when I convert it to NSData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass in the view that contains your image and mask to this method (I use this as an extension of UIImage)

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

this will return your 'flattened', masked image (make sure the UIView has a clear background)

you will then need to convert to PNG (not JPG) before creating a PFFile, this will retain the transparency.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Where can I look to learn about why I lost the mask when converting the UIImage to NSData?  This is really unclear to me.

Comment: The masked UIImage you had was only masked at runtime - i.e. the original image was in memory, but had instructions to display with a mask. my method resamples the visible view to a new image.